# Best Practice (Keeping it simple) to wrap a method returning List of Products from DAL to BLL

Tags: c#, oop, data-access-layer, bll

Below is a method from from my console application calling a DAL method. Whats the best way to wrap this in a BLL method so it can be called directly from the presentation? I have worked on projects in the past where we called everything from the DAL such as below, however would nt it be best to get everything from BLL?

```
public static void getAllProducts(int ID)
{
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
    ProductDA productDA = new ProductDA();

    productList = productDA.GetAllProducts(ID);

    foreach (Product product in productList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ProductID:" + product.ProductID);
        Console.WriteLine(" Product Name:" + product.ProductName);
        Console.WriteLine(" Product Date:" + product.ProductDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If most of the project gets the data from Stored Procedures already built and in Production that work fine, would it be best to just refrence the DAL rather than double wrap things in a BLL?

Comment: My Solution: return type of List AND having to add .ToList() to my for each iterator.Any objections/comments anyone? public static List<Product> GetAllProducts(int ID) { List<Product> ProductList = new List<Product>(); ProductDA ProductDA = new ProductDA(); ProductList = ProductDA.GetAllProducts(ID); foreach (Product Product in ProductList.ToList()) {ProductList.Add(Product);} return ProductList; }

Answer (score 0):

The best way is not at all.

- It should be a Get method that is IQueryable.

Then you would expose it through a repository service in the business layer that... has Get : IQueryable again.

THis would allow users to write:

Get ().Where (x=> x.ProductId= 223 || x.ProductName.StartsWith ("someproduct")).

Flexible.

Comment: why IQueryable and not IEnumerable<>? The DAL obviously already returns a List?

Comment: I would disagree with this. If you pass IQueryables you have no distinction between layers. That IQueryable can be modified and actually run from anywhere in your stack. When using a repository I would expect an IEnumerable to be passed back.

Comment: Flexible, but completely non-performant.  If you cannot control queries, you will get full table dumps/queries that don't use indexes/queries that ask the database to do conversions that it shouldn't.

Comment: I agree. Definitely not performance. At least once you get faster than real time financial data processing where I use seomething like that pefectly. Btw., a proper interim layer generates pass through sql, aggregates it via local caches and handles this efficiently. That, though, obviously requires some smart programming. IQueryable is NOT IENumerable - it allows the recipient to analyze the query and generate proper SQL. You basically et a tree of nodes.

Comment: Using a repository doesn't mean that you got a complete table dump. Well, it do if you google repository pattern. But no production implementations do. Most have a mechanism to limit number of rows returned (when quering the DB). Returing a IQueryable from Nhibernate or EntityFramework would indeed leak datalayer specific code to the other layers (as handling db exceptions etc)

Comment: Only if you dont wrap them. Otherwise all it does "leak" is the ability to define exdact queries WHERE YOU NEED THEM, which seriously cuts down repetitive code.